# Flutter drop-down delay with data fetching

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to build a UI that would display items matching current selection of categories. I've got the main parts "working" but would like to display Progress Indicator while I'm fetching items for the newly selected category. Presently, the UI changes to selection only after the data has been fetched which makes it look a bit clunky. How should I change the code so that the "selection" in drop-down becomes instant, and while I fetch the matching items, I display a progress indicator, and once the data is ready, I display the item fields. Full dartpad here: https://dartpad.dev/?id=3754f586870f7976d9321ebec34fbdde

Code here:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const SignUpApp());
}

class SignUpApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const SignUpApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => BrowseScreen(),
        '/welcome': (context) => const WelcomeScreen(),
        '/browse': (context) => BrowseScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class BrowseScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  BrowseScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<BrowseScreen> createState() => _BrowseScreenState();
}

class _BrowseScreenState extends State<BrowseScreen> {
  late final Future<List<EquipmentCategory>> categories;
  late final Future<List<Equipment>> matchingEquipment;
  late List<Equipment> equipment = [];
  String dropdownValue = '';

  //For local testing without Firebase
  final List<EquipmentCategory> equipmentCategories = [
        EquipmentCategory('1iyQmcbWIV6gNMk5PX9E', 'Lawn & Garden - motorised'),
        EquipmentCategory('ofYNwqKtvbctjiwETKOZ', 'Trailers'),
        EquipmentCategory('r5FSAIyIrinkr8m1TXTj', 'Lawn & Garden - manual'),
      ];

  final List<Equipment> trailerEquipmentList = [Equipment(id: 'd9A8qfHT8lKIzhUk55K5', name: 'Two-wheel trailer 900mm', categories: ['ofYNwqKtvbctjiwETKOZ'], photos:    ["https://media.prod.bunnings.com.au/api/public/content/c65c035a7c7b4a7282c3b5f3def5ec76?v=94a4edf7&t=w500dpr1"])];

  late final Map<String, List<Equipment>> equipmentByCategory = {
    'ofYNwqKtvbctjiwETKOZ': trailerEquipmentList,
    '1iyQmcbWIV6gNMk5PX9E': [],
    'r5FSAIyIrinkr8m1TXTj': []
  };

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('initState');
    categories = _fetchEquipmentCategories();
    dropdownValue = '1iyQmcbWIV6gNMk5PX9E';
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: categories,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                // while data is loading:
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                      valueColor:
                          new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue)),
                );
              } else {
                print("Refreshing");
                return Container(
                    color: CupertinoColors.white,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                    child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          Column(children: [
                            DropdownButton<String>(
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
                              elevation: 16,
                              style:
                                  const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
                              underline: Container(
                                height: 2,
                                color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                              ),
                              onChanged: (String? value) {
                                _fetchEquipment()
                                    .whenComplete(() => setState(() {
                                      dropdownValue = value!;
                                      print("Dropdown value: $dropdownValue");
                                    }));
                              },
                              items: snapshot.data
                                  .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                                      (EquipmentCategory value) {
                                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                  value: value.id,
                                  child: Text(value.name),
                                );
                              }).toList(),
                              value: dropdownValue,
                            ),
                            if(equipment.isNotEmpty)
                              Text('NOT EMPTY'),
                            if (equipment.isEmpty)
                              Text('EMPTY'),
                            Column(children: <Widget>[
                              // equipment.map<Text>((Equipment value) { return Text(e.name)}).toList()
                              for(var item in equipment) const Text(style: TextStyle(color:  Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0)), 'ITEM')
                            ],)
                            
                          ])
                        ]));
              }
            }));
  }

  Future<List<EquipmentCategory>> _fetchEquipmentCategories() async {
    return Future.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 1),
      () => equipmentCategories,
    );
  }

  Future<List<Equipment>?> _fetchEquipment() async {
    equipment = equipmentByCategory[dropdownValue]!;
    print('Equipment by category length: ${equipment.length}');
    return Future.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 1),
      () => equipmentByCategory[dropdownValue],
    );
  }

  _printCategoriesValues() {
    print('_printCategoriesValues');
    categories.then((result) => {
          print(result.length),
          for (var cat in result) {print('Category: ${cat.name}')}
        });
  }

  _browseEquipment() {
    print('_browseEquipment');
  }
}

class EquipmentCategory {
  String id;
  String name;

  EquipmentCategory(this.id, this.name);
}

class Equipment {
  late String id;
  late String name;
  late List<String> categories;
  late List<String> photos;

  Equipment({required id, required name, required categories, required photos});

  factory Equipment.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Equipment(
        id: json['id'],
        name: json['name'],
        categories: json['categories'],
        photos: json['photos']);
  }
}

class _WelcomeFormState extends State<WelcomeScreen> {
  @override
  State<WelcomeScreen> createState() => _WelcomeFormState();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: CupertinoColors.white,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          MyButton(
            text: 'Browse',
            icon: CupertinoIcons.search,
            callback: _showAvailableEquipmentScreen,
          ),
          MyButton(
            text: 'Return',
            icon: Icons.recycling,
            callback: () {},
          ),
          MyButton(
            text: 'Login',
            icon: Icons.login,
            callback: () {
              showCupertinoDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) => CupertinoAlertDialog(
                  title: Text('Hello, World!'),
                  actions: [
                    CupertinoDialogAction(
                      child: Text('Close'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showAvailableEquipmentScreen() {
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/browse');
  }
}

class WelcomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const WelcomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<WelcomeScreen> createState() => _WelcomeFormState();
}

class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyButton({
    super.key,
    required this.text,
    required this.icon,
    required this.callback,
  });

  final String text;
  final IconData icon;
  final VoidCallback callback;

  final double buttonSize = 90;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoButton(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      minSize: 0,
      onPressed: callback,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: const Color(0xFFEAEAEA),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
        ),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          vertical: 20,
          horizontal: 30,
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: buttonSize,
                  height: buttonSize,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: CupertinoColors.black,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(17),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: buttonSize,
                  height: buttonSize,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: CupertinoColors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  ),
                  child: Icon(
                    icon,
                    size: 60,
                    color: CupertinoColors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            Text(
              text,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                color: CupertinoColors.black,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have asked two separate questions:

1. *How should I change the code so that the "selection" in
   drop-down becomes instant,*
2. *"and while I fetch the matching items, I display a progress indicator"*

**2:**

set a variable at your class level for `isLoading`:

```dart
class _BrowseScreenState extends State<BrowseScreen> {
  
 bool isLoading = false;
...
```

then, after. your Dropdown's code, use a conditional

```dart
Column(children: [
  // --> ... Code to display dropdown here, add it here.
  if (isLoading)
    CircularProgressIndicator()
  else ...[
    if (equipment.isNotEmpty) Text('NOT EMPTY'),
    if (equipment.isEmpty) Text('EMPTY'),
  ],
```

**1:**

```dart
onChanged: (String? value) {
  // --> step 1 - set state to loading
  setState(() {
    dropdownValue = value!;
    isLoading = true;
  });
  // --> step 2 - fetch equipment and set state to not loading when complete
  _fetchEquipment().whenComplete(() =>
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
        print("Dropdown value: $dropdownValue");
      }));
},
```

---

Here's a complete runnable snippet using your example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const SignUpApp());
}

class SignUpApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const SignUpApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => BrowseScreen(),
        '/welcome': (context) => const WelcomeScreen(),
        '/browse': (context) => BrowseScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class BrowseScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  BrowseScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<BrowseScreen> createState() => _BrowseScreenState();
}

class _BrowseScreenState extends State<BrowseScreen> {
  bool isLoading = false;
  late final Future<List<EquipmentCategory>> categories;
  late final Future<List<Equipment>> matchingEquipment;
  late List<Equipment> equipment = [];
  String dropdownValue = '';

  //For local testing without Firebase
  final List<EquipmentCategory> equipmentCategories = [
    EquipmentCategory('1iyQmcbWIV6gNMk5PX9E', 'Lawn & Garden - motorised'),
    EquipmentCategory('ofYNwqKtvbctjiwETKOZ', 'Trailers'),
    EquipmentCategory('r5FSAIyIrinkr8m1TXTj', 'Lawn & Garden - manual'),
  ];

  final List<Equipment> trailerEquipmentList = [
    Equipment(
        id: 'd9A8qfHT8lKIzhUk55K5',
        name: 'Two-wheel trailer 900mm',
        categories: [
          'ofYNwqKtvbctjiwETKOZ'
        ],
        photos: [
          "https://media.prod.bunnings.com.au/api/public/content/c65c035a7c7b4a7282c3b5f3def5ec76?v=94a4edf7&t=w500dpr1"
        ])
  ];

  late final Map<String, List<Equipment>> equipmentByCategory = {
    'ofYNwqKtvbctjiwETKOZ': trailerEquipmentList,
    '1iyQmcbWIV6gNMk5PX9E': [],
    'r5FSAIyIrinkr8m1TXTj': []
  };

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('initState');
    categories = _fetchEquipmentCategories();
    dropdownValue = '1iyQmcbWIV6gNMk5PX9E';
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: categories,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                // while data is loading:
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                      valueColor:
                          new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue)),
                );
              } else {
                print("Refreshing");
                return Container(
                    color: CupertinoColors.white,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                    child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          Column(children: [
                            DropdownButton<String>(
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
                              elevation: 16,
                              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
                              underline: Container(
                                height: 2,
                                color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                              ),
                              onChanged: (String? value) {
                                // --> step 1 - set state to loading
                                setState(() {
                                  dropdownValue = value!;
                                  isLoading = true;
                                });
                                // --> step 2 - fetch equipment and set state to not loading when complete
                                _fetchEquipment().whenComplete(() =>
                                    setState(() {
                                      isLoading = false;
                                      print("Dropdown value: $dropdownValue");
                                    }));
                              },
                              items: snapshot.data
                                  .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                                      (EquipmentCategory value) {
                                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                  value: value.id,
                                  child: Text(value.name),
                                );
                              }).toList(),
                              value: dropdownValue,
                            ),
                            if (isLoading)
                              CircularProgressIndicator()
                            else ...[
                              if (equipment.isNotEmpty) Text('NOT EMPTY'),
                              if (equipment.isEmpty) Text('EMPTY'),
                            ],
                            Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                // equipment.map<Text>((Equipment value) { return Text(e.name)}).toList()
                                for (var item in equipment)
                                  const Text(
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0)),
                                      'ITEM')
                              ],
                            )
                          ])
                        ]));
              }
            }));
  }

  Future<List<EquipmentCategory>> _fetchEquipmentCategories() async {
    return Future.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 1),
      () => equipmentCategories,
    );
  }

  Future<List<Equipment>?> _fetchEquipment() async {
    equipment = equipmentByCategory[dropdownValue]!;
    print('Equipment by category length: ${equipment.length}');
    return Future.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 1),
      () => equipmentByCategory[dropdownValue],
    );
  }

  _printCategoriesValues() {
    print('_printCategoriesValues');
    categories.then((result) => {
          print(result.length),
          for (var cat in result) {print('Category: ${cat.name}')}
        });
  }

  _browseEquipment() {
    print('_browseEquipment');
  }
}

class EquipmentCategory {
  String id;
  String name;

  EquipmentCategory(this.id, this.name);
}

class Equipment {
  late String id;
  late String name;
  late List<String> categories;
  late List<String> photos;

  Equipment({required id, required name, required categories, required photos});

  factory Equipment.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Equipment(
        id: json['id'],
        name: json['name'],
        categories: json['categories'],
        photos: json['photos']);
  }
}

class _WelcomeFormState extends State<WelcomeScreen> {
  @override
  State<WelcomeScreen> createState() => _WelcomeFormState();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: CupertinoColors.white,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          MyButton(
            text: 'Browse',
            icon: CupertinoIcons.search,
            callback: _showAvailableEquipmentScreen,
          ),
          MyButton(
            text: 'Return',
            icon: Icons.recycling,
            callback: () {},
          ),
          MyButton(
            text: 'Login',
            icon: Icons.login,
            callback: () {
              showCupertinoDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) => CupertinoAlertDialog(
                  title: Text('Hello, World!'),
                  actions: [
                    CupertinoDialogAction(
                      child: Text('Close'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showAvailableEquipmentScreen() {
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/browse');
  }
}

class WelcomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const WelcomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<WelcomeScreen> createState() => _WelcomeFormState();
}

class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyButton({
    super.key,
    required this.text,
    required this.icon,
    required this.callback,
  });

  final String text;
  final IconData icon;
  final VoidCallback callback;

  final double buttonSize = 90;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoButton(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      minSize: 0,
      onPressed: callback,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: const Color(0xFFEAEAEA),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
        ),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          vertical: 20,
          horizontal: 30,
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: buttonSize,
                  height: buttonSize,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: CupertinoColors.black,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(17),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: buttonSize,
                  height: buttonSize,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: CupertinoColors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  ),
                  child: Icon(
                    icon,
                    size: 60,
                    color: CupertinoColors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            Text(
              text,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                color: CupertinoColors.black,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```